# Baritone clefs, difference between these two

Tags: notation, clefs

I am using the Clefs app from the Google Play store.

I would like to know, why are there two baritone clefs and what is the difference between them?

If they are different, then why haven't they been named differently (also, to avoid confusion)?

[image: Clefs app - Lesson editor - select clefs screen, two different Baritone clefs circled (one is an F-clef, the other is a C-clef)]

Comment: Its surely sufficent, to know where to look up anything under the *other keys* section, since I have never encountered them in real life (but singers may have a different experience).

Comment: Just learn the four most common clefs and forget the rest: you're unlikely to ever come across them. And if you ever do, then **that** is the time to learn them.

Comment: Echoing @PiedPiper here, yes you will get through 99% of your music life only knowing treble and bass clef, plus maybe alto if you're a violist.

Comment: I'd argue that you don't need to know any clef unless/until you want to read music in it. It's good to have a general idea that there's more than one but if you ever only use treble, why bother learning even bass. But really it's just "middle of spiral is G, ball and two dots is F, beak is C" and then you either build up fluency as you're using it, or you don't because there's no reason to.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef#Baritone_clef%E2%80%A0):

> When the F-clef is placed on the third line, it is called the baritone clef. Baritone clef was used for the left hand of keyboard music (particularly in France; see Bauyn manuscript) and for baritone parts in vocal music. A C-clef on the fifth line creates a staff with identical notes to the baritone clef, but this variant is rare.

Answer (score 2):

This is the alto clef.

[image]

It is used for the viola most of the time and frequently encountered in orchestral scores.  As you have probably already learned, the clef points to middle C.  In this position, C is on the middle line.

It is one of the many positions that the C clef can occupy.  The C clef, often called the "movable" clef, appears in several different positions in several circumstances.  First, many older (1600s) choral scores will use it in many different positions.  Soprano clef (middle C on the bottom line) for sopranos, alto clef for altos, and so on.  The thinking was, I believe, that composers would use these clefs to avoid ledger lines.  Anything that fit on the staff was roughly within the range of that voice type.  During the classical period, three trombone parts in would be printed in alto, tenor, and bass clefs, to be played on alto, tenor, and bass trombones.  Also, several tenor-*ish* instruments in the orchestra currently use this movable clef when the instrument is supposed to play higher notes.  Trombone, bassoon, and cello parts will often use the tenor clef, for example, especially in solos.

As for this clef,

[image]

I have seen it in theory books and orchestration books but I haven't seen it elsewhere.  Since this clef points to F on this middle line, and the other version of baritone clef points to C on the top line, they are interchangeable and equivalent.  You are unlikely to see either clef very often, however.

Answer (score 1):

The bass-like one places F to the third line. The alto-like one places C to the fifth line (counting from the bottom up, in case it's done the other way around in your country). So clearly they're equivalent to one another.

As for how come there are two in existence, they were probably invented independently.